# Formatting integers with periods instead of commas

Tags: python, formatting

I wanted to ask if anyone can help me format some numbers.

I'll give you some examples:

first example:

`{{'{: .2f}'. Format (number)}}` is equivalent to: `1000000,00`.

second example:

`{{'{: n}'. format (number)}}` is equivalent to: `1.000.000,0000000`

I would like to get this formatting, if is possible, `1.000.000,00`

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html)

Comment: Very kind, thank you